# php Session doesn't destroy

Tags: php, html, session

i build a website and it has a sign in form, when user sign in, the sign in form will not appear, and a sign out will apprear instead

my problem is when the user sign out the session doesn't destroy

when user sign in , i got to the function run, when user sign out i go to the function sign out

#### HTML

```
<?php
        Session::init();
        $l = Session::get('loggedIn');
        if (isset($l) && $l==true) {
                ?>
        <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/signout" class="smallLink">sign out</a>
            <?php

        } else {
            ?>
            <a href="login/run">Sign in</a>
            <br/>
            <form action="<?php echo URL;?>login/run" method="POST">
                <div class="staticSignin">
                    phoneNumber
                    password
                </div>
                <div id="userInputSignin">
                    <input type="text" name="MNumber"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password"/>
                    <input type="image" src="http://localhost/Mar7ba/public/images/signinButton.png"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

#### run for sign in

```
Session::init();
            $row = $sth->fetch();
            $ID = $row['ID'];
            $rollID = $row['rollID'];
            Session::set('loggedIn', true);
            Session::set('ID', $ID);
            Session::set('roolOfUser', $rollID);
```

#### sign out

```
 public function signout() {
        Session::set("loggedIn", false);
        Session::destroy();
        $this->view->render('index/index');
    }
```

#### Session Class

```
<?php

class Session {

    public static function init() {
        session_start();
    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {

        @$_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$key]))
            return $_SESSION[$key];
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        unset ($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

when sign out , the sign in form doesn't appear

Comment: instead of using unset ($_SESSION); try session_unset();

Comment: @MrD i tried it , and stil the signout button appear, and the sign in form doesn't appear

Comment: print out the $_SESSION variable and see what you get? and you should use session_unset(); always to avoid issues with global varibles rather than unset ($_SESSION)

Comment: when i tried to echo it, i had this exception `Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mar7ba\libs\Session.php on line 21` , maybe the exception appear this time because i put exit after destroy session

Comment: @MrD and now when i remove the Session::init() from the html code, the sign in form always appear and the sign out button never appear

Comment: $this->view->render('index/index'); <- can you show us the html of this? is it the same you posted?

Comment: My guess would be you have something there that accidentally initializes the session and logs in the user again before the output is sent

Comment: @Mahn i shown u the $this->view->render above

Comment: @Marcio Simao has given you the right answer, how silly no one noticed before :)

Comment: @Mahn i am starting the session , please see Session::init()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To destroy a session you need first to start it using `session_start()`, seems that you aren't doing this

Try to do it:

```
session_start();

// Deleting all content in $_SESSION
$_SESSION = array();

// Destroying the session
session_destroy();
```

**EDIT 1**

Try to do these changes in `destroy()` to test if the session is really being started:

```
public static function destroy() {

    session_start();

    // Deleting all content in $_SESSION
    $_SESSION = array();

    // Destroying the session
    session_destroy();

}
```

Comment: no i am using session_start(); look at the Session:init(), and i tried your solution already and still that problem

Comment: and when i remove the Session:init() from HTML, the sign out button never appear

Comment: @tottiroma, Try to do what i said in EDIT 1 and tell me what happens.